# Cron always fails and manual execution always succeeds. How?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a job that runs calculations nightly and stores results in sqlite files google storage. The scheduled task always succeeds when I manually run. It always fails when cron (Google Cloud Scheduler) runs it. The logs don't give a meaningful error message.  502 error code.  Starts a new instance which should not matter. I set up the cron.yaml to retry 2 times. But all executions fail.

My cron.yaml

```
- description: "PAPER GO calc from alpaca to /tmp/entries.sqlite"
  target: default
  url: /calcentriesindb
  schedule: every sun,mon,tue,wed,thu  20:00
  timezone: America/New_York
  retry_parameters:
    job_retry_limit: 2
    min_backoff_seconds: 30
```

The top log entry is the manual execution.  The following 3 are the cron attempts.[image]

Complete log entry from 502 error

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog",
    "appId": "s~wc2022-356423",
    "versionId": "20220730t143529",
    "requestId": "62eb0c5d00ff0bb76d8eabcbfc0001737e7763323032322d3335363432330001323032323037333074313433353239000100",
    "ip": "0.1.0.2",
    "startTime": "2022-08-04T00:01:33.767986Z",
    "endTime": "2022-08-04T00:01:34.565759Z",
    "latency": "0.797773s",
    "method": "GET",
    "resource": "/calcentriesindb",
    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
    "status": 502,
    "responseSize": "288",
    "userAgent": "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)",
    "urlMapEntry": "auto",
    "host": "default.wc2022-356423.uc.r.appspot.com",
    "cost": 3.2186e-8,
    "taskQueueName": "__cron",
    "taskName": "05697141537686660811",
    "wasLoadingRequest": true,
    "instanceIndex": -1,
    "finished": true,
    "instanceId": "00c61b117c3c5fa64d13a841d4e8db781b8d5f07b01c3875537cbb754a073373efdb153e58e5d70a725960c452ea04b253df39c0c286628e0dec6d",
    "line": [
      {
        "time": "2022-08-04T00:01:34.565621Z",
        "severity": "INFO",
        "logMessage": "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."
      }
    ],
    "appEngineRelease": "1.9.71",
    "traceId": "115ab8ca6be26417bc63bb90824dbd71",
    "first": true,
    "traceSampled": true,
    "spanId": "1960824541831512114"
  },
  "insertId": "62eb0c5e0008a2c1355ad083",
  "httpRequest": {
    "status": 502
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "gae_app",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "wc2022-356423",
      "zone": "us16",
      "module_id": "default",
      "version_id": "20220730t143529"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-08-04T00:01:33.767986Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "labels": {
    "clone_id": "00c61b117c3c5fa64d13a841d4e8db781b8d5f07b01c3875537cbb754a073373efdb153e58e5d70a725960c452ea04b253df39c0c286628e0dec6d"
  },
  "logName": "projects/wc2022-356423/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log",
  "operation": {
    "id": "62eb0c5d00ff0bb76d8eabcbfc0001737e7763323032322d3335363432330001323032323037333074313433353239000100",
    "producer": "appengine.googleapis.com/request_id",
    "first": true,
    "last": true
  },
  "trace": "projects/wc2022-356423/traces/115ab8ca6be26417bc63bb90824dbd71",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-08-04T00:01:34.572846740Z",
  "spanId": "1960824541831512114",
  "traceSampled": true
}
```

The critical function getting called from a handler:

```
func CalcEntriesInDb() (interface{}, error) {
    symbols, err := getTradableSymbols()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("getTradableSymbols failed.", err)
    }

    log.Println(len(symbols), "symbols to scan.")
    createPath(c.EntryDbPath) // forces a specific path to exist including creation of folders.
    runList := GetRunList(c.RefDbPath)
    ////loadHistory because of weekends and holidays lets gather more than 13 days to get enough trail for minlow
    rowcount, err := loadHistory(20, symbols, c.EntryDbPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(`Running `, len(runList), `sql scripts.`)
    runSqlScripts(runList, c.EntryDbPath)

    err = gcsUp(c.EntryDbPath)
    sendEmail("Entries Calculated", PrintTableHTML(c.EntryDbPath, "entry"), c.EntryDbPath)

    return rowcount, err
}
```

Here's the excerpt from my indexHandler

```
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    spew.Dump(r.URL.Query())
    params := r.URL.Query()
    var apikey string
    log.Println("X-Appengine-Cron", r.Header["X-Appengine-Cron"])
    //log.Println(params["marina"])
    if len(params["marina"]) == 1 {
        apikey = params["marina"][0]
    }

    if len(r.Header["X-Appengine-Cron"]) > 0 || apikey == c.Apikey {
        log.Println("Key or Param passed.")
    } else {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }
    //spew.Dump(r.URL.Path)
    switch r.URL.Path {
    case "/calcentriesindb":
        resp, err := CalcEntriesInDb()
        if err != nil {
            _, err = fmt.Fprint(w, err)
        } else {
            _, err = spew.Fprint(w, resp)
        }
```

Comment: In my GAE, I used to redirect all http requests to https, but this breaks cron because cron won't follow redirects.  Now, I redirect all http requests to https except for my cron links.

Comment: Would need to see your code to see what is going on.  Is there something in the code that stops execution without returning a 2xx response?  For example, if the user is not logged in, does it just stop?

Comment: As a bonus test, I added the same task as a Cloud Scheduler task with nothing specific to app engine (not using cron.yaml).  Gave it 2 retries again. That automation also fails with the same 502 error code. .

Comment: Code now posted in question.

Comment: As further evidence that something is broken with Google Cloud Scheduler  specifically, I just scheduled a cron task to call the function from a digital ocean hosted server and it worked exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got gae cron working.
I created a cron entry that includes the apikey.  This is a workaround, not a fix.
Instead of scheduling `/calcentriesindb`
I scheduled `/calcentriesindb?marina=apikey`.  I wrote my code to not need the api key when executing from app engine cron. Oh well.
Something is definitely still broken with how app engine handles schedule requests.
Also if you didn't see in other comments--scheduling the request from a completely different server using curl worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a similar problem but I can't recollect if the status code was 502. What used to happen for me was - when I ran a job via the Cron UI, it would report a 'Failed' status but if I manually invoked the job, it would successfully complete.

I later figured out that the issue was - cron jobs are meant to return a status of between 200 - 299 (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml)). The route being invoked by my cron job added a task to a queue and then redirected to my home page (this meant it was returning a 301). I changed it to return a fixed text (e.g. "done") which is a 200 status and that fixed the issue.

Comment: If I understand your issue, your cron task was actually executing but just reporting an incorrect status.  I doublechecked my gcs bucket and confirmed the sqlite file it's supposed to generate isn't happening.  Not a status issue for me.

Comment: Got it. Maybe post your code snippet for folks to debug??

Comment: Code now posted.